# Why is Win32 unable to load?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-studio-2013

I'm programming in c++ on Visual Studio 2013. I made a console application with input and output. I made special commands. I compiled and ran the application. I typed a command and clicked enter. When I did it crashed and threw errors at me such as:

```
'Andersen Archive.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\Wyatt\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Andersen Archive\Debug\Andersen Archive.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'Andersen Archive.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
'Andersen Archive.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
'Andersen Archive.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
'Andersen Archive.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcr120d.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
'Andersen Archive.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcp120d.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
The program '[1812] Andersen Archive.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

What is wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message

> The program '[1812] Andersen Archive.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0

means that your program exited successfully.

Process exit code 0 means "success" in both Window and *nix.

I.e. it did not crash.

Apparently you ran it in the debugger, and then it doesn't stop automatically at the end. Either run it without debugger (Ctrl F5 in Visual Studio, or run it in the command line), or e.g. place a breakpoint on the last right curly brace of `main`.